# "cannot find symbol" when trying to close I/O objects

Tags: java, exception

```
public static int howMany(String FileName)
{
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try
    {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(FileName);
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dis));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.print("FILE DOESN'T EXIST");
    }
    finally
    {
        fis.close();
        dis.close();
        br.close();
    }


    String input;
    int count = 0;

    try
    {

        while ((input = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            count++;
        }

    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        System.out.print("I/O STREAM EXCEPTION");
    }


    return count;
}
```

For some reason, I cannot close any I/O objects. fis.close(), dis.close(), br.close() all give me cannot find symbol even though I imported all the I/O library (import java.io.*;) and initiated all the objects.

Comment: hurr i get error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown 3 times now

Answer (score 5):

```
 BufferedReader br = null;
 FileInputStream fis =null;
 DataInputStream dis null;
 try {
     fis = new FileInputStream(FileName);
     dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
     br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dis));
 }
```

Put them out of your `try block`, so that your finally block can see the variables.

Comment: hurr i get error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown 3 times now

Comment: @MatthewLoch put another catch block and catch IOException. but make sure that your catch hirarchey is catch(FileNotFound){}catch(IOException)

Comment: @MatthewLoch you are welcome. please tickthe anser accepted if you think it solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare *all* the streams outside the `try` block, otherwise they won't be visible in the `finally` block:

```
FileInputStream fis = null;
DataInputStream dis = null;
BufferedReader br = null;
```

Alternatively, you could use Java 7's new [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax to automate resource closing.

Answer (score 1):

your objects are being  null inside your block

```
FileInputStream fis =null;
DataInputStream dis null;
```

define them outside the block something like this

```
try{

    fis = new FileInputStream(FileName);
    dis = new DataInputStream(fis);

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have scoped `fis` to inside the try block so the final doesn't know it's there. Try:

```
FileInputStream fis;
DataInputStream dis;
try
    {
        fis = new FileInputStream(FileName);
        dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dis));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
BufferedReader br = null;
FileInputStream fis = null;
DataInputStream dis = null;
try
{
    fis = new FileInputStream(FileName);
    dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dis));
}
```